# Multiple subviews being added to UIScrollview

Tags: swift, uiscrollview

On my users profile page, there is a scrollview users slide across to see more photos. Everything works with adding the photos but the problem is that each image added to the scrollviews subview, is added twice. This is the code I am using to populate the scrollview. I currently have an Imageview embed inside the scrollview on storyboard and use that as the default if user has no photos. The at the bottom should show the bug. I have tried using a combination of clipstobounds, scaleaspectfit, and setting background color to clear but nothing stops from showing an additional image in the background. Any ideas would be appreciated. On a side note, the bug is only noticed on the iphone 8 plus

```
 var pages: Int = 1
    var numPhotos: CGFloat = 1
    var position: CGFloat = 1
    let scrollWidth: CGFloat = profileImage.frame.width
    let scrollHeight: CGFloat = profileImage.frame.height
    let scrollY: CGFloat = profileImage.frame.origin.y

 if let profileImg = user.profileImage {
        profileResource = ImageResource(downloadURL: URL(string: profileImg)!, cacheKey: profileImg)
        profileImage.kf.setImage(with: profileResource)
    } else {
        profileImage.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "requests_icon")
    }

    nameLbl.text = user.fullName
    influenceLbl.text = "\(user.score)"
    followersLbl.text = "\(user.followers)"
    followingLbl.text = "\(user.following)"

    if let image1 = user.photo1 {
        let imageOne = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: scrollWidth * position, y: scrollY, width: scrollWidth, height: scrollHeight))
        imageOne.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        photo1Resource = ImageResource(downloadURL: URL(string: image1)!, cacheKey: image1)
        imageOne.kf.setImage(with: photo1Resource)
        pages = pages + 1
        numPhotos = numPhotos + 1
        position = position + 1
        scrollView.addSubview(imageOne)
    } else {

    }

    if let image2 = user.photo2 {
        let imageTwo = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: scrollWidth * position, y: scrollY, width: scrollWidth, height: scrollHeight))
        imageTwo.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        photo2Resource = ImageResource(downloadURL: URL(string: image2)!, cacheKey: image2)
        imageTwo.kf.setImage(with: photo2Resource)
        pages = pages + 1
        numPhotos = numPhotos + 1
        position = position + 1
        scrollView.addSubview(imageTwo)
    } else {

    }

    if let image3 = user.photo3 {
        let imageThree = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: scrollWidth * position, y: scrollY, width: scrollWidth, height: scrollHeight))
        imageThree.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        photo3Resource = ImageResource(downloadURL: URL(string: image3)!, cacheKey: image3)
        imageThree.kf.setImage(with: photo3Resource)
        pages = pages + 1
        numPhotos = numPhotos + 1
        position = position + 1
        scrollView.addSubview(imageThree)
    } else {

    }

    scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: profileImage.frame.width * numPhotos, height: scrollHeight)
    scrollView.delegate = self
    scrollView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    scrollView.clipsToBounds = true

    pageControl.numberOfPages = pages
    pageControl.currentPage = 0
}

func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView){
    let pageWidth:CGFloat = scrollView.frame.width
    let currentPage:CGFloat = floor((scrollView.contentOffset.x-pageWidth/2)/pageWidth) + 1

    self.pageControl.currentPage = Int(currentPage)
}
```

[image]

Comment: Why are you using scroll view ? It is most better if you use collection view.

Comment: the scrollview is inside a collectionviewreusableview

Comment: It's weird, Can I knwo, why are you using scrollView inside collectionView ?

Comment: its for design purposes

Comment: Are these code inside viewDidLoad Method ? Have you tried with viewWillAppear ? May be you required to update layout. Is scollView Adding Images for vertical scrolling or horizontal ?

Comment: Its for horizontal scrolling. The code is within a configurecell function called by viewforsupplementaryelementofkind